# Firebase is sending OTP more than once

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**My Firebase login activity code is like this. And on successful login of user. When I enter the dashboard or MainPage where I open another Fragment 'A'. It sends me OTP again and again.
Below is the code of my login activity:**

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
String verificationCodeBySystem;
String county_code;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
   firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   //Button listener b1 ..
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                phonenumber = e1.getText().toString();
               
                                sendVerificationCodeToUser(phonenumber);
                       
                    }
             });

    mCallbacks  = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationCodeBySystem =s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code=phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if(code!=null){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Verification Failed because: \n"+e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}

private void sendVerificationCodeToUser(String phonenumber) {
    phonenumber= county_code+phonenumber;
    PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phonenumber)
            .setTimeout(60L,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(this)
            .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
            .build();
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

}

private void verifyCode(String codeByUser) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential= PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationCodeBySystem,codeByUser);
    signInByTheUser(credential);
}

private void signInByTheUser(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,MainPage.class));
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Verification Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 /* This commented code closes application with null ptr exception
                   reference=null;
                   firebaseAuth=null;
                   mCallbacks=null; */
                    finish();
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Sorry Something went Wrong ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   
                }
            });
}

 /*This code too close application when i successfully login and open the other fragment.
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Destroy() called...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    reference=null;
    firebaseAuth=null;
    mCallbacks=null;
}
 

*/
}
```

Please contact me directly on twitter and linkedin for doubts.
https://www.linkedin.com/in/akshit-mangotra-86114518a/
https://twitter.com/AkshitMangotra

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Ok thanks @AlexMamo